# SQL Server Agent Job failing

Tags: sql

I recently started to support a project for which databases are maintained in SQL Server 2008 R2.

There is a SQL server agent DBMR job which was running fine until couple of days back. Now it's been failing with error " Could not find stored procedure 'XXX' ". When I looked in the master database, that procedure is not there.

Is there a way (logs or event viewer like application) from sql server management studio I can find out if a SP has been deleted by someone recently ?

Under a strong assumption no one would have deleted any SP's .. I am really puzzled as to how this job was running fine until 2 days and failing now. Any suggestions / idea's welcome. Thanks.

Comment: There could be a chance to change permission for the user on which this job has been running can cause this issue. Ask DBA's to check whether that SP exists or not. If they says that doesn't exists then some one has been deleted otherwise ask them to grant earlier permissions.

Comment: Permission is not the issue as there are few other jobs which are running fine under the same user.

Comment: For yours information, each object can have different permissons, certainly we have to get the confirmation from DBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions/answers.

One of our engineers tried to install a different DBMR version and this deleted some of the jobs, SP's etc. Sorry if wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL);
```

using above query you will be able to identify the dropped stored procedure details

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) AS Script FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS' AND Context = 'LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST' AND AllocUnitName = 'sys.sysobjvalues.clst' AND [TRANSACTION ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [TRANSACTION ID] FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE Context IN ('LCX_NULL') AND Operation IN ('LOP_BEGIN_XACT') AND [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ' AND CONVERT(nvarchar(11), [Begin Time]) BETWEEN '2013/07/31' AND '2015/08/1') AND SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0])) <> 0;
```

using the above pasted query you can regenerate the deleted procedures

for the safe side i have taken  the begin time between 2013 and 2015 dates so then result set should include all the dropped procedures (objects)

hope this will help you

for more reading

https://serverfault.com/questions/69056/how-to-find-when-the-stored-procedure-was-deleted-and-who-deleted-it

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-a-specific-dropped-object/

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-recover-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [fn_dblog](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/)

```
SELECT 
    Operation,
    [Transaction Id],
    SUSER_SNAME([Transaction SID]),
    [Transaction Name],
    [Begin Time],
    [SPID],
    Description
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
GO
```

Execute this in the database where the object was deleted.